# Textarea New Line on Enter Key not working on .NET Core MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

I have a (probably) simple issue that I can't solve and need your help to resolve.

I created a new MVC application with Visual Studio 2017.  I then created the necessary Model, View, and Controller to add some data to a SQL Server database.
However, in the TEXTAREA input, I am not able to use the Enter Key to go to a new line, like I am able to do here when I submitted this question.  The Enter key does nothing.

I tried to trace the issue and was able to use this script to confirm that the Enter key was detected; however, still can't get a new line when I pressed the Enter key.

```
                <script>
                    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
                        if ((event.which == 13) && ($(event.target)[0] == $("textarea")[0])) {
                             alert("One");
                            //  event.preventDefault();
                            // return false;
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```

Second, I added an onclick event to the textarea itself and still did not get a new line when clicked.  There must be an override for the textarea in code that I am not able to find, which is probably part of the default app build in .NET VS2017.

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="20" class="form-control" asp-for="Notes" style="width: 96% !important;" onclick="this.value='Hello \n How R U?'"></textarea>
```

Is there any way to correct this issue and gain access to the full TEXTAREA functionalities and be able to provide a full text-based area for users to provide detailed comments in multiple lines?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote following HTML code to face your problem but there was no problem!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
test
</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="6" cols="20" class="form-control" asp-for="Notes" style="width: 96% !important;" 

onclick="this.value='Hello \n How R U?'"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Did you check your application by another browser?
If the problem still remains, In your browser inspect HTML code of your textarea and compare it to the tag helper equivalent of the textarea in your view code. This may help you to figure something out.

Comment: I was using a jquery implementation code on the header of the page.  I removed it and was then able to use the enter key on the textarea. Hence, I found another more current jquery datepicker implementation, which does not seem to interfere with the rest of the CSS and JS scripts. Specifically, I was using JQuery version 3.3.1 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js), which is preventing enter key carriage return to generate a new line on TextArea forms.  Once I changed to JQuery 1.12.4 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js)  the page (textarea) is working again.